# Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property, JS executing before page renders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am receiving the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘value’ of null
```

What I'm attempting to do is copy text input from one input box into another, when you click the checkbox the value of one input will be copied into another input.

**HTML**

```
<input name="stry" type="text" id="stry"/> 
<input type="checkbox" name="sendsms" onclick="CopyStory(this.form)">

<div id="container">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="body">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function CopyStory(f) {
  if(f.sendsms.checked == true) {
    f.stry.value = f.body.value;
  }
}
```

I believe the problem is that the code is executed before the elements load because I have a javascript alert modal pop-up which prevents the page from loading unless you press 'Ok'

**Alert JS**

```
$('#container').fadeOut('fast').delay(7000).fadeIn('fast');
alert("This page is loading....");
```

I've tried wrapping it around document.ready(function blah... but then it gives me an error that:    " 'CopyStory' is not defined".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4z20mtym/1/).

**JS**

```
function copyStory(ch) {
                if(ch.checked)
                var text1 = document.getElementById("stry").value;
                else
                text1='';
                document.getElementById("second").value = text1;             
                }

$('#container').fadeOut('fast').delay(7000).fadeIn('fast');
alert("This page is loading....");
```

**HTML**

```
<input name="stry" type="text" id="stry"/> 
<input type="checkbox" name="sendsms" onclick="copyStory(this)">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="second" name="body">
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, wrap your code in `$(function(){ //code here });` to execute your js after page loads.

About `'CopyStory' is not defined`:
when you define function like:

```
$(function(){
   function CopyStory(){ //... }
});
```

`CopyStory` is not visible in global scope, so if you want to fix your problem just change defenition to:

```
$(function(){
    window.CopyStory = function(){ //... }
});
```

p.s. assign a variable to `window` propery is the only way to define global variable inside a local scope.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `form` tags and trying to access a form..!

Try this,

```js
function CopyStory(f) {
  if(f.sendsms.checked == true) {
      console.log(f.body.value);
    f.stry.value = f.body.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
<form>
<input name="stry" type="text" id="stry"/> 
<input type="checkbox" name="sendsms" onclick="CopyStory(this.form)">

<div id="container">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="body">
</form>
</div>
```

Just put the js script inside `<head></head>`